# Override encoding value in XML file

Tags: python, xml, encoding

I am reading .xml files using the Python library `xml.etree.ElementTree`. My .xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?>
<Parent>
  <Field1>7933</Field1>
  <Field2>9.26</Field2>
  <Field3>Montana</Field3>
  <Field4>Blue</Field4>
</Parent>
```

The file has an empty string as its encoding attribute, which is causing an error:

`ParseError: XML declaration not well-formed: line 1, column 30`

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
xtree = et.parse(file_name, parser=et.XMLParser(encoding="UTF-8"))
```

I tried to pass an `XMLParser` object as an argument to `et.parse()`, hoping that specifying the encoding would help, but the error did not change.

How do you override an empty string encoding value?

Comment: Try using `BeautifulSoup` -- `soup = BeautifulSoup(open(file_name), 'xml')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lxml` module [offers a `recover=True`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html) option to try to handle this type of issues

```
from lxml import etree
xtree = etree.parse('tmp.xml', parser=etree.XMLParser(recover=True))
xtree.xpath('//*[1]')
[<Element Parent at 0x7f12f6f90208>, <Element Field1 at 0x7f12f780c488>]
```

Comment: This solution works thank you!

Comment: @lawrence you may accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file content to a string, replace the encoding attribute value using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and then use [`xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring):

```py
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

file_name = "77275440.xml"

# <?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?>
regex_string = r"([<][?]xml version[=][\"]1.0[\"].* encoding[=][\"])([\"][?][>].*)"

with open(file_name) as file:

    xml_content = file.read()
    xml_content = re.sub(regex_string, r"\1UTF-8\2", xml_content)

xtree = et.fromstring(xml_content, parser=et.XMLParser(encoding="UTF-8"))
```

Alternatively, if you can be 100% sure that your XML files use UTF-8 encoding, the XML declaration does not contain any other information and the XML file is always formatted, i.e., the XML declaration is on a separate (first) line, you could also just skip the first line:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

file_name = "77275440.xml"

with open(file_name) as file:

    xml_content = "".join([
        line for line in file.readlines()[1:]
    ])

xtree = et.fromstring(xml_content, parser=et.XMLParser(encoding="UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the xml declaration, if you are sure the encoding is utf-8. Maybe it is better to check with `encoding, chardet or cchardet package` or something.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# read standard is encoding='utf-8'
with open('xfile.xml', 'r') as f:
    # skip the xml_declaration! can be add later by write()
    next(f)
    x = f.read()

xml = ET.fromstring(x)
ET.dump(xml)

tree = ET.ElementTree(xml)
ET.indent(tree, space="  ")
tree.write("test.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Output:

```
<Parent>
  <Field1>7933</Field1>
  <Field2>9.26</Field2>
  <Field3>Montana</Field3>
  <Field4>Blue</Field4>
</Parent>
```

And a file with xml declaration is created:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Parent>
  <Field1>7933</Field1>
  <Field2>9.26</Field2>
  <Field3>Montana</Field3>
  <Field4>Blue</Field4>
</Parent>
```

Comment: This works provided that (a) there is an XML declaration, and (b) it is on a line of its own. Neither assumption is going to be true for all possible input documents.

Comment: @Michael Kay I am fully agree, this application which create such damaged xml should be repaired.